# Channel as parameter, why not an asterisk?

Tags: go

When I pass a channel as a parameter to close it at the end of the function, I don't need to put * before it to refer to the channel in the main-function scope. But when I'm supposed to set a WaitGroup to done (wg.Done()) I have to so, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because internally, the `chan` is somewhat a struct made of pointers. You don't need to send a pointer to it. On contrary, the `sync.WaitGroup` is a classical struct

```
type WaitGroup struct {
    state1 [12]byte
    sema   uint32
}
```

for whose all methods are declared with a pointer receiver, so you need to pass a pointer to it around to use it in different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

In Go, `chan` is a language primitive, and `sync.WaitGroup` is a struct.  Because Go passes parameters by value the `WaitGroup` would be passed as a copy, and the `chan` would be passed like an `interface` which is implemented as a primitive type with metadata including a pointer to the implementation details.